# Do I need @Transactional with ElasticsearchRepository?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-transactions

I have a question do I need to annotate methods that use findBy.. methods of ElasticsearchRepository with @Transactional in spring boot ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No! you don't need `@Transactional`. 
There is no such thing as a transaction in Elasticsearch. Elasticsearch does not support ACID transactions. Changes to individual documents are ACIDic, but not changes involving multiple documents.